# PHP Telegram Bot, broadcast a message at a certain time of the day

Tags: php, telegram-bot

is it possibile to broadcast a certain message at a certain time of the day?
For example, I want my script to broadcast a message every day at 7am, but without cronjob, because I don't want to execute the script externally.
Also, I can't use `sleep()`, because it will sleep the bot.

Is there any chance to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without cron jobs this is not possibile

if you don't want to use your web site cronjobs you can use online cron job services like :

https://ifttt.com/

Comment: after a while , webscript.io closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with telegram "job queue", I use it in Python but not in PHP. I think it exists in PHP too.

Every time an event was triggered, in its function you can set next event.